# CountIFS with filter

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Syntax:

```
CountIfS(Range1, condition1, Range2, Condition2,.... So on)
```

Can we use `FILTER` function to retrieve a value.

I am trying below function

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A610, "Yes", $B$2:$B$610, FILTER(Sheet2!14:14, Sheet2!2:2=G1))
```

The output is not correct answer, neither the its throwing any error.

I could save the output of `filter(Sheet2!14:14,Sheet2!2:2=G1)` in different cell and refer that cell in 2nd condition. But for that I need make plethora cells as I need to use this countifs function in every column.

PS : `filter(Sheet2!14:14,Sheet2!2:2=G1)` returns the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

that's not how it works. the output of your FILTER formula needs to be exactly 609 cells to match the range of your COUNTIFS formula. only then your formula will work.

in your case try:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(A2:A; A2:A="yes"; REGEXMATCH(B2:B; 
 TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; FILTER(Sheet2!14:14; Sheet2!2:2=G1))))))
```